# SwiftUI making buttons closer to each other horizontally in an HStack

Tags: swift, button, swiftui

I tried to make buttons closer to each other horizontally on the keyboard. First I tried adjusting the width of button frame. But I found that if I decrease the frame width, some long-width character like "W" will not show up correctly.

[image]

Then I tried making spacing of the HStack to be negative like what I did in the code below.

[image]

But this will cause the button overlap with each other and the clickable area will shift to the left which is not acceptable(can be checked by setting background color as blue).

[image]

Is there a way to decrease button distance without changing font size?

```
struct KeyboardView: View {

    let KeyboardStack = [["Q", "W", "E", "R", "T", "Y", "U", "I", "O", "P"],
                          ["A", "S", "D", "F", "G", "H", "J", "K", "L"],
                          ["Z", "X", "C", "V", "B", "N", "M"]]

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 9) {                      
            ForEach(KeyboardStack.indices) { row in
                let num = KeyboardStack[row].indices
                HStack(spacing: -12) {           
                    ForEach(num) { column in
                        Button(KeyboardStack[row][column]) {}
                        .frame(width: 12, height: 12,alignment: .center)
                        .padding()
//                        .background(Color.blue)
                        .font(.system(size: 15, weight: .regular, design: .default))
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
                    }
                }
                .frame(width: 255, height: 19.5, alignment:.center)
            }
        }
        .frame(width: 445, height: 60, alignment:.center)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first easy thing to do is get rid of your `padding()` modifier that is adding extra padding to each button.

I'm assuming, given that it's a keyboard view that you want all of your keys to be the same width. You can use a `PreferenceKey` to store the maximum width needed to fit a certain letter and then use that for each `Button`, making it only as large as needed:

```
struct KeyboardView: View {
    @State private var keyWidth : CGFloat = 0
    
    let KeyboardStack = [["Q", "W", "E", "R", "T", "Y", "U", "I", "O", "P"],
                         ["A", "S", "D", "F", "G", "H", "J", "K", "L"],
                         ["Z", "X", "C", "V", "B", "N", "M"]]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 9) {
            ForEach(KeyboardStack.indices) { row in
                let num = KeyboardStack[row].indices
                HStack(spacing: 0) {
                    ForEach(num) { column in
                        Button(action: {}) {
                            Text(KeyboardStack[row][column])
                                .font(.system(size: 15, weight: .regular, design: .default))
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                                .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
                                .frame(width: keyWidth)
                                .background(GeometryReader {
                                    Color.clear.preference(key: KeyWidthKey.self,
                                                           value: $0.frame(in: .local).size.height)
                                })
                                .contentShape(Rectangle())
                        }
                    }
                }.onPreferenceChange(KeyWidthKey.self) { keyWidth = $0 }
                
            }
        }
    }
}

struct KeyWidthKey: PreferenceKey {
    static var defaultValue: CGFloat { 0 }
    static func reduce(value: inout Value, nextValue: () -> Value) {
        value = max(value, nextValue())
    }
}
```

Note that this solution will continue to work if you change the font size, as it is not dependent on a hard-coded `frame` size for each key.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. That surely works, but the clickable area will also depend on the shape of characters. For example, the button of character "i" will become extremely hard to be triggered. Any suggestions?

Comment: Sure -- add `.contentShape(Rectangle())`. I've updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

Here is a refactored code and way for you:,

*PS: There is still lot lots of room to make more refactored, like getting rid of hard code values and making keys and keyboard sizes dynamic depending on screen size and so on like support for other languages or small or capital words, adding sound to key press the list can go on and on. Here is a simple way for you to start or use this way for your need.
That is why there is a big team working in apple just for keyboard, it seems simple thing but the keyboard in iOS that we are using it is more complex than we know it is an app in our app, when we need type something through keyboard.*

[image]

[image]

```
struct KeyboardView: View {

    let keyBackgroundColor: Color
    let keyForegroundColor: Color
    let keyboardBackgroundColor: Color

    init(keyBackgroundColor: Color, keyForegroundColor: Color, keyboardBackgroundColor: Color) {
        self.keyBackgroundColor = keyBackgroundColor
        self.keyForegroundColor = keyForegroundColor
        self.keyboardBackgroundColor = keyboardBackgroundColor
    }
    
    init() {
        self.keyBackgroundColor = Color.gray
        self.keyForegroundColor = Color.primary
        self.keyboardBackgroundColor = Color.gray.opacity(0.5)
    }

    private let keyboard: [[String]] = [["Q", "W", "E", "R", "T", "Y", "U", "I", "O", "P"],
                                        ["A", "S", "D", "F", "G", "H", "J", "K", "L"],
                                        ["Z", "X", "C", "V", "B", "N", "M"]]
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack(spacing: 5.0) {
            
            ForEach(keyboard.indices) { row in
                let num = keyboard[row].indices
                
                HStack(spacing: 5.0) {
                    
                    ForEach(num) { column in
                        
                        keyBackgroundColor.cornerRadius(2.0)
                            .frame(width: 24.0, height: 24.0)
                            .overlay( Text(keyboard[row][column])
                                        .font(.system(size: 15.0, weight: .regular, design: .default))
                                        .foregroundColor(keyForegroundColor)
                                        .fixedSize() )
                            .onTapGesture { print(keyboard[row][column]) }
                        
                    }
                }
                
            }
        }
        .padding(5.0)
        .background(keyboardBackgroundColor.cornerRadius(5.0))
        
    }
}
```

### use case with some custom code:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You could get rid of both `init`s if you made each color a `var` instead of `let` with a default value. Then, it any color could get passed in (or not) by the synthesized initializer.

Comment: But my plan was to have snap keyboard use case! just like: `KeyboardView()` and a customized one with an init! Normally KeyboardView does not need change color time by time in app, that is why let can fit well.

Comment: Using `var` with default values would work exactly the same as what you have now, but would just allow it to be optional to use the parameters and you wouldn't have to define *either* `init`. You could still write `KeyboardView()`, or `KeyboardView(keyForegroundColor: .blue)`, etc.  Just define the properties at the top of the `struct` like `var keyBackgroundColor: Color = Color.gray` and `var keyForegroundColor: Color = Color.primary`

Comment: I know what you mean, if I made in the way you explained, the user of code could chose the same color for foreground without knowing that I used that color as default for background key. It is just a failure example. It could be same issue in other part of views that user wants use as well beside another or over a custom view. My plan was given a clear understanding to user of code, about the colors that been chosen.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use `Button` as only a wrapper view, build your button's content instead of using string directly. You can control its layout easily.

```
VStack(spacing: 4) {
    ForEach(keys.indices) { row in
        HStack(spacing: 3) {
            ForEach(keys[row].indices) { column in
                Button {
                    print("Tap \(keys[row][column])")
                } label: {
                    Text(keys[row][column])
                        .font(.system(size: fontSize))
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .frame(minWidth: fontSize)
                        .padding(3)
                        .background(
                            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 2)
                                .fill(.black)
                        )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Result

[image]

Comment: The only use case of Button instead of just Text is given tap effect! Since the pressed button is always under finger it would never get noticed! The only feedback from iOS keyboard is sound and some big bobble of letter! if you try iOS keyboard they do not show pressed situation. But since it is a custom code you can do what ever you like

Comment: @swiftPunk i don't think they build ios keyboard with swiftui. the question is not about technique to implement keyboard :D